# Сортировка массива по убыванию

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Всем привет. Необходимо отсортировать массив по убыванию, используя конкретный ключ.

Код:

```
$result = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $value) {
    $result[$i]['example'] = $value;
}
$data = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]  = $value['example'];
}
array_multisort($data, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $result);
```

Но, дело в том, что он сортирует по 1 или 2 цифре, то есть:

Есть числа: 9, 927, 99, 97. В отсортированном виде будет выглядеть так: 99, 97, 927, 9.

Comment: @evansive, какой тип данных под ключом 'example'? И хорошо бы показать часть исходного массива.

Comment: Если ожидаете только целые числа, попробуйте так

    $data[$key]  = intval($value['example']);

Массив `$result`, судя по вашему коду, вообще остается пустым.

Кстати, а чего вы хотите добиться этими метаморфозами?

    foreach($row as $value) {
        $row[$i]['example'] = $value;
    }

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не подходят встроенные [rsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) и [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) ?

Согласно [Документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/) (можно на [русском](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/)) первая умеет сортировать в обратном порядке массивы, вторая - то же, но при этом сохраняет ключи (в ассоциативном массиве, естественно)